# autofs ~/.hidden: No such file or directory

Tags: autofs

I am mounting [home drives using autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs#Wildcard_characters) from a file server:

auto.master

```
/home   /etc/auto.home
```

auto.home

```
*   tyrell:/nfshome/
```

This seems to work great, but on the file server, `tyrell` I'm constantly getting this error:

```
Apr 27 13:38:08 tyrell rpc.mountd[1145]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.1.164:691 for /nfshome/.hidden (/nfshome) 
Apr 27 13:38:08 tyrell rpc.mountd[1145]: can't stat exported dir /nfshome/.hidden: No such file or directory
```

Why is it looking for a .hidden folder and how can I get the client to stop trying to mount it?

The clients are running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem for people going back to [2004](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=122313), and which has recently been re-addressed [March 2017](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1437754).  It is due to "user-friendly" tools like Nautilus seeking to implement a **hidden files** feature. To do this it looks for a file called `.hidden` at the top of a filesystem for a list of filenames to hide.  This causes autofs to try to mount this file from your server. (There is similar code in `glib` to implement the same feature).

Perhaps you can try revising the `*` map in your `/etc/auto.home` to be less encompassing. Or if you configure your desktop to *not* ignore hidden files, pehaps it will not look for the magic file. I'm not able to try any working solutions for the moment.